# Unwanted vertical spacing within sentence

Tags: floats, parskip

I encountered some weird spacing within my document and could reproduce it with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,BCOR0pt,DIV12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=it, skip=-12pt, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, margin={2mm,0mm},hang]{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=it, skip=-12pt, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, margin={2mm,0mm}]{bicaption}
\captionsetup[figure][bi]{labelfont=it, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false, margin={0mm,0mm}}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\figurename{Bild}}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-first]{name=Bild}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Fig.}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{4.0cm}{\hbox to 4.0cm{#1#2\hfill}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4cm\relax}{#3}\par}
\captionsetup[figure][bi]{format=4.0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
%
\begin{figure}[t]
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5cm}
  \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\bicaption[indention=0pt]{Dies ist eine sehr lange Unterschrift in zwei Sprachen die über eine Zeile hinaus geht}{This is supposed to be a very long multiline caption in two languages} 
\end{figure}\vspace*{5.8mm}
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5cm}
  \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
  \bicaption[indention=0pt]{Beispiel 2}{Example 2}
\end{figure}\vspace*{5.8mm}
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
\end{document}
```

This give me the output:
[image]
As I understand Latex floating boxes concept and appreciate it most of the time, for placing figures at the right spot it seems to be troubling sometimes. So avoiding harsh options like the `\usepackage{float}` and the option `[H]` I manage to get along with `[h!]` and the other placings. But from time to time, it seems in cases with not enough text and too many figures I encounter this weird vertical space within a sentence (correspondent to the `parskip`).

How can I avoid this behaviour without losing the control of `[h!]` and the other options?

Comment: unrelated to the space (which is simply the `\vspace` added explicitly) but `[h!]` is in almost all cases a bad choice of option (normally it generates a warning from latex) its main effect is to stop latex adding the float at top of page, bottom of the page or on a page just containing floats (no, `t`, `b`, `p`)  so it makes it very hard for latex to find anywhere to place the float and increases the chance of it drifting to the end of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5cm}
  \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\bicaption[indention=0pt]{Dies ist eine sehr lange Unterschrift in zwei Sprachen die über eine Zeile hinaus geht}{This is supposed to be a very long multiline caption in two languages} 
\end{figure}\vspace*{5.8mm}
```

This adds vertical space after the end of  the current line. Exactly as you have. You probably want this vertical space inside `figure` environment.

Comment: Thanks, as you recommended I simply included the vspace inside the environment and it worked! Still I find it odd, that the vspace is also influenced by the parskip size defined in the preamble.

Comment: @Jäger the space is not related to the parskip, it is just the space that is supplied as argument.

Answer (score 2):

The space is the `\vspace*{5.8mm}` that you have added.

Because of the `%` before and after the float the float has been added within the paragraph, and floats to the top of the page, which means that the vspace has been added in horizontal mode within a paragraph. a vspace in such a position adds space after the current line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Together with the second answer this solves the question!

Comment: @Jäger note that adding the vspace inside the float, while much better than putting it outside is still the wrong approach, you typically need different spaces depending on whether another float is below or the text block and latex adds those spaces as \textfloatsep and \floatsep which are set in the class or preamble, it should never be necessary to have vspace in every float